# which value I have to pass to a variable $model in yii booster TbActiveForm

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I tried to use yii booster widgets to create the form with TbActiveForm.

I saw some examples 
related to the TbActiveForm like to create textfield,

`<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model, 'textField', array('class'=>'input-small')); ?>`

But I am worried about the variable `$model`. Can anyone please help me with this.

I am first time working with yii booster and yii framework. please help me on this.

Comment: Your question shows, that you didn't even read the most basic documentation for Yii. You can't expect us to help you with every single step of your learning effort. So please first learn [some basics](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.overview) first and only ask questions that where not covered elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It the object that u pass to the view which contain the attributes to hold your data as shown

The model class would be as shown

```
class UrModelname extends CFormModel{
      public $textfile;
      ..
      ..
}
```

Check your controller you will get this code there

```
$model=new UrmodelName();
$this->render('viewname',array('model'=>$model))
```

In your example textfield is the attribute referenced by the $model object

Answer (score 0):

Yii Booster offers an easier way to build a form from our model, so the $model variable should be the class of your model that extends CActiveRecord.

you can use gii to create model from your table, for example table user.
then you will get model User located at protected/model/User.php, User has username and password attribute.

then when you want to use textFieldRow, you can use it like this to create new User

```
$model = new User;
$form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
'id'=>'user-form',
));
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'username'); ?>
<?php echo $form->passwordFieldRow($model,'password'); ?>
$this->endWidget();
```

So, the $model variable should be your new User model or your active model

Comment: Actually it can be any subclass of `CModel`, not only `CActiveRecord`